# R treemap - keep the colours for several maps

Tags: r

I am working on a treemap that is an output from the site REVIGO.

I would like to define a colour for each "representative" term so I can keep it the same in several maps that I want to produce. for example, reproduction red, transport blue... or any other way that enables to keep me the same colours for the same label of the "representative" column.

Here is the script.

I am quite new to R, any help is highly appreciated!

```
# treemap package by Martijn Tennekes

# Set the working directory if necessary
# setwd("C:/Users/username/workingdir");

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Here is your data from REVIGO. Scroll down for plot configuration options.

revigo.names <- c("term_ID","description","freqInDbPercent","value","uniqueness","dispensability","representative");
revigo.data <- rbind(c("GO:0000003","reproduction",0.769,13.0000,1.000,0.000,"reproduction"),
c("GO:0006810","transport",17.616,38.0000,0.958,0.000,"transport"),
c("GO:0006950","response to stress",4.575,48.0000,0.799,0.000,"response to stress"),
c("GO:0009991","response to extracellular stimulus",0.473,5.0000,0.811,0.438,"response to stress"),
c("GO:0009628","response to abiotic stimulus",0.571,19.0000,0.824,0.448,"response to stress"),
c("GO:0007165","signal transduction",6.621,28.0000,0.676,0.637,"response to stress"),
c("GO:0009607","response to biotic stimulus",0.342,14.0000,0.829,0.421,"response to stress"),
c("GO:0009605","response to external stimulus",1.370,27.0000,0.814,0.501,"response to stress"),
c("GO:0009606","tropism",0.006,1.0000,0.845,0.561,"response to stress"),
c("GO:0009719","response to endogenous stimulus",0.526,15.0000,0.825,0.443,"response to stress"),
c("GO:0007275","multicellular organism development",1.559,49.0000,0.708,0.000,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0006412","translation",5.686,10.0000,0.831,0.614,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0007267","cell-cell signaling",0.407,4.0000,0.841,0.197,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0009908","flower development",0.030,1.0000,0.757,0.640,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0040029","regulation of gene expression, epigenetic",0.130,2.0000,0.882,0.229,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0005975","carbohydrate metabolic process",5.260,6.0000,0.913,0.134,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0019748","secondary metabolic process",0.138,2.0000,0.896,0.158,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0019538","protein metabolic process",18.489,38.0000,0.888,0.191,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0006259","DNA metabolic process",5.607,14.0000,0.852,0.407,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0006464","cellular protein modification process",7.726,21.0000,0.845,0.265,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0019725","cellular homeostasis",1.253,5.0000,0.834,0.224,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0007049","cell cycle",1.885,24.0000,0.853,0.100,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0006139","nucleobase-containing compound metabolic process",26.547,49.0000,0.856,0.123,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0006629","lipid metabolic process",3.522,16.0000,0.855,0.112,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0008219","cell death",0.458,9.0000,0.864,0.200,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0016049","cell growth",0.153,2.0000,0.872,0.179,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0009856","pollination",0.044,1.0000,0.839,0.614,"multicellular organism development"),
c("GO:0007610","behavior",0.170,3.0000,0.949,0.000,"behavior"),
c("GO:0008152","metabolic process",75.387,149.0000,0.987,0.000,"metabolism"),
c("GO:0009056","catabolic process",4.820,27.0000,0.939,0.000,"catabolism"),
c("GO:0009987","cellular process",63.780,324.0000,0.982,0.000,"cellular process"),
c("GO:0040007","growth",0.317,4.0000,0.950,0.000,"growth"),
c("GO:0006091","generation of precursor metabolites and energy",1.940,1.0000,0.907,0.020,"generation of precursor metabolites and energy"),
c("GO:0009058","biosynthetic process",31.611,64.0000,0.947,0.033,"biosynthesis"),
c("GO:0016043","cellular component organization",7.239,76.0000,0.919,0.050,"cellular component organization"),
c("GO:0007154","cell communication",7.219,33.0000,0.919,0.062,"cell communication"));

stuff <- data.frame(revigo.data);
names(stuff) <- revigo.names;

stuff$value <- as.numeric( as.character(stuff$value) );
stuff$freqInDbPercent <- as.numeric( as.character(stuff$freqInDbPercent) );
stuff$uniqueness <- as.numeric( as.character(stuff$uniqueness) );
stuff$dispensability <- as.numeric( as.character(stuff$dispensability) );

# by default, outputs to a PDF file
pdf( file="revigo_treemap_biological_process_subcluster2_drop.pdf", width=16, height=9 ) # width and height are in inches

# check the tmPlot command documentation for all possible parameters - there are a lot more
treemap(
    stuff,
    index = c("representative","description"),
    vSize = "value",
    type = "categorical",
    vColor = "representative",
    title = "",
    inflate.labels = FALSE, 
    drop.unused.levels = FALSE, # set this to TRUE for space-filling group labels - good for posters
    lowerbound.cex.labels = 0,   # try to draw as many labels as possible (still, some small squares may not get a label)
    bg.labels = "#CCCCCC00",     # define background color of group labels
                                                       # "#CCCCCC00" is fully transparent, "#CCCCCCAA" is semi-transparent grey, NA is opaque
    position.legend = "none"
)

dev.off()
```